# what is causing this error "UserAgent not available, file operations may not be optimized. "

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, administration

I am working on an enterprise wiki site collection inside SharePoint 2013, and sometimes especially when modifying the wiki page name , users will get the following exception :-

[image]

I checked the logs and i find the following error "UserAgent not available, file operations may not be optimized. ... ". so can anyone adivce on this please?
Thanks

**Edit**

Here is the log file uploaded to onedrive after enabling verbose logging , correlation id = 4bce009d-3c69-c0b7-30fc-0153080d3219 :-

[onedrive link](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=bfd0ad6f15ef78dd&id=BFD0AD6F15EF78DD!135&authkey=!AMJhemq8BeB2xNQ)

i found the following 2 exceptions inside the log file :-

- 04/27/2015 12:51:36.38*   w3wp.exe (0x4640)                           0x225C  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High        ...ecutionStep.Execute()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)     at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompl...  4bce009d-3c69-c0b7-30fc-0153080d3219
- 04/27/2015 12:51:36.49    w3wp.exe (0x4640)                           0x225C  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WssObjectCache.RemoveItemFromCache(Guid webId, Guid itemGuid, Boolean isList)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WssObjectCache.HandleChanges(SPChangeCollection changes)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CacheManager.CheckForChanges(SPSite site, Boolean forceGetChanges)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CacheManager.GetManager(SPSite site, Boolean useContextSite, Boolean allowContextSiteOptimization, Boolean refreshIfNoContext)

Comment: The "User agent..." Is surely not the root cause of this error (it does not throw an exception like that)

Comment: enable the verbose logging level and then share the it here. From this log i can see, user having issue due to Trusted Provider...

Comment: @RobertLindgren so what do u think the problem is ?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE can you please check my edit , i have enabled the verbose logging , and i re-generate the problem, i have uploaded the log file to the onedrive ?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE did u have the chance to check the logs after i have enabled the Verbose logging...

Comment: @RobertLindgren can you please check my edit , i have uploaded the full log file to the onedrive ,,, seems there are two exceptions one related to "Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WssObjectCache.RemoveItemFromCache" while the other related to "System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification"

Comment: i am seeing this error "Application error when access /kb/CustomerServiceKB/Pages/test page new.aspx, Error=Object reference not set to an instance of an object." look like whatever your designing is not being liked by sp.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE thanks for the reply. now when i created the wiki page i name it "test page", then i entered the wiki page content and i change its name from "test page" to "test page new" then i save the wiki page ,, after that i got the exception,,,  as i mentioned this error only appear if the user rename the wiki page ... so could this help in knowing how i can solve this problem ?

Comment: As others have mentioned, the "UserAgent not available" bit is not what you're looking for. I see that all the time and ignore it. The "object reference not set to an instance" error is probably the actual issue - that's a very common error in SharePoint.

Comment: @Omegacron so how i can fix this ? can u adivce more on this please?